# Disabled Button if Textbox nil Ruby on Rails / Devise / Simple Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, devise, simple-form

I am trying to have a class change if the text field of my Simple_form is empty/nil and using ruby not jquery to do so.

My goal is to have a button disabled if the user has not put any text in and allow them to comment once they have. 
    
    <%= simple_form_for([@message, @message.comments.build]) do |f| %>

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.input :content, label: "Reply" %>
  </div>

  <% if @message.comments.present? %>
    <%= f.button :submit, class: "ui disabled button" %>
  <% else %>
    <%= f.button :submit, class: "ui green button" %>
  <% end %>

<% end %>
</div>
```

Let me know if I am heading the right direction with this?

Comment: This will never work without client side code (javascript / jquery), Ruby is ineterpreted by the server, so it's either disabled or enabled forever. Also, the `if` you are using is not doing what you expect, this is checking if there are any comments on the message, ruby can't detect when there's content present, so on a :new action the button will always be disabled.

Comment: It is task for js (because can be executed without your server), if you do it on ruby - form should be rerendered from server after each user change, but user  at the time of the request can change more data. attempt to do it on the ruby is doomed to strange bugs and server overloading. On js it is 1-2 line of code and no troubles.

Comment: How would you handle it with JS?

Comment: like that - button = document.querySelector('button');
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('change', function(e){if (e.target.value){button.disabled = false} else {button.disabled = true};})

Comment: "_using ruby not jquery_" literally impossible. For manipulating the DOM use Javascript.